# Is Doctype needed for HTML5 documents

Tags: html, w3c

Recently I had a job interview and one of the questions was "Is doctype needed for HTML 5 documents?". I've answered "no" but have a feeling that I might be wrong. From the [w3](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) it looks like it is absolutely required, but if I type a simple HTML like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="color" disabled/>
    </body>
</html>
```

save it as HTML and try to open in Chrome - it would work perfectly well, with a new color input (disabled). That input is HTML5 as well as attribute.

So the question is - do I need to specify doctype or not? What would be the correct answer for the interview?

Comment: I guess you could argue that without the `Doctype` element it isn't an HTML5 document.

Comment: You can type `hello world` in a text editor, save it as HTML, and it will render in Chrome.  Turns out Chrome (and many other browsers) put stuff in for you, even if it's "required."

Comment: The correct answer is "some of them".   A better question would be "Is doctype *mandatory* for HTML5 documents?"

Answer (score 20):

The correct answer would be "It depends".

A DOCTYPE is optional for HTML5 documents in the [XHTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/the-xhtml-syntax.html#writing-xhtml-documents) (i.e., XHTML5 documents):

> XML documents may contain a DOCTYPE if desired, but this is not required to conform to this specification.

A DOCTYPE is required for HTML5 documents in the [HTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#writing):

> Documents must consist of the following parts, in the given order:
>
> […]
>
> 3. A DOCTYPE.

#### Exceptions

- HTML5 documents in the [`srcdoc` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc) of an [`iframe` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) don’t need a DOCTYPE:

  > 2. Optionally, a DOCTYPE.

Comment: This is the complete answer if “is needed” is interpreted as “is required by specifications”. It could also be interpreted as referring to practical effects. In that case, the answer would be that a doctype string is needed in HTML syntax to put browsers to “standards mode”.

Comment: I would like this answer better if you elaborated as to when a document is html vs xhtml. What does this mean to the browsers -- how do they decided which syntax to evaluate with?

Comment: See this question for details about XHTML vs HTML5: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5

Answer (score 9):

I, too, would have answer "no" (wrongly, as it happens).

However, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype  says :

> 8.1.1 The DOCTYPE
>
> A DOCTYPE is a required preamble.
>
> DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend
>   to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some
>   specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures that the
>   browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant
>   specifications.

BTW, G.I.Y.F

Comment: The quoted part applies to HTML syntax only.

Comment: And the question title is "Is Doctype needed for HTML5 documents" (Q.E.D).

Comment: The HTML5 specification clearly and noticeably says that it defines two syntaxes for HTML5, one based on original HTML and one fully conforming to XML. What you quote does not answer the question, since it applies to one of the syntaxes only.

Comment: Ah! Finally I understand. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to write a w3c standard-conformant HTML5 document, then `<!DOCTYPE html>` is required.

But in practice you don't always need a doctype because any common web browser will render your document regardless. However, some browsers will then use a legacy mode in which some features are not interpreted correctly and instead in a way an earlier version of the browser handled it (most of them layout-related).

Which answer is right *for this interview*? That depends on the mentality of the person who interviewed you. In a job interview it doesn't matter if you are right or wrong. It only matters what impression you make on the interviewer.

Comment: The interesting question to me is,  is the DOCTYPE HTML5 required in practice in the year 2020? What do the current browsers (FF, Chrome, Edge) do if I omit it yet make the code HTML-5 compliant?

Comment: Only one way to find out :) You probably need to specifically make the code not XHTML-compliant to be sure.